# How to go child menu when click on parent menu item in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is my site http://www.hopebras.com/. I want that, when i click on `ABOUT` page , it will go to `HOPE` page. Here `HOPE` is a child menu of `ABOUT` menu. That means it will go to this page http://www.hopebras.com/hope/. currently it is going to the http://www.hopebras.com/about/ page. Please tell me, How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt make sense keeping the About page separately if you don't use it. Especially from a SEO point of view. I see you've fixed that already, but please, get rid of the About page under these circumstances. It is useless, unless you want to make it show up somewhere else. Either way, About should go to about page, if About exists, that from a UI/UX point of view.